# Java subtract value of char code in string

Tags: java, character-encoding, windows-1255

I am trying to convert string to hebrew encoding (windows 1255) so I need to substract from the value of any char 1264 and put here in new string.

this is the code in javascript that I am trying to convert:

```
strText = strText.replace(/[א-ת]/ig, function(a,b,c) {
        return escape(String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0)-1264));
    });
```

And this is what I made in Java but I am not getting the expected value:

```
String test = "שלום";
byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes();
String testResult = "";
for (int i = 0;i < testBytes.length;i++)
     {
        testResult += (char)((int)testBytes[i]-1264);
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a `byte` array, the maximum number that can be stored is 255, and the minimum is 0, so it can only store extended ASCII characters (afaik it doesn't cover hebrew characters). What you need is a `char` array (can store any unicode character).

So, change this

```
byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes();
```

to this

```
char[] testBytes = test.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thanks its helped, now how can I convert it to url style encoding.I need to convert only 4 chars, and not full url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the encoding when you call [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29). Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "שלום";
    try {
        byte[] testBytes = test.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String testResult = new String(testBytes, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(testResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output is

```
שלום
```

Comment: But I want to convert it to windows-1255.the substraction change the text to the encoding.

Comment: No. You would never subtract like that to change the encoding. You can pass a different encoding to `new String` or `getBytes()`.

Comment: What can I do?this is the only way I found to change it.do you know other way to convert utf-8 to windows-1255 that support android?Thanks.